# bash nested while: outer loop executed only once

Tags: bash, while-loop, nested-loops

The outer loop in the following bash script is executed only once, but it should be executed four times:

```
#!/bin/bash 
NX="4"
NY="6"
echo "NX = $NX, NY = $NY"
IX="0"
IY="0"
while (( IX < NX ))
do
  while (( IY < NY ))
  do
    echo "IX = $IX, IY = $IY";
    IY=$(( IY+1 ))
  done;

  IX=$(( IX+1 ))
done
```

I have also tried declaring the loop variables as `declare -i NX=0` (without quotes), but either way the output I get is

```
NX = 4, NY = 6
IX = 0, IY = 0
IX = 0, IY = 1
IX = 0, IY = 2
IX = 0, IY = 3
IX = 0, IY = 4
IX = 0, IY = 5
```

What is the reason for this and how do I fix it? Note that I prefer to leave `NX="4"` and `NY="6"` (with quotes), as these will actually be sourced from another script.

Comment: write `echo "IX = $IX"` after the first `do` and you'll see it loops perfectly! That is, it loops from 0 to 3. Give more context on what you want to do, so we can assist.

Comment: Why are you using `while` loops rather than `for` to start with? `for ((ix=0; ix<nx; ix++))` would have been more readable, and have avoided this bug.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The `while` comes from a skript that I edited to suit my needs. I simply didin't include the variable reset, hence the error. Of course, `for` works fine - but I was so confused by the large number of alternatives for the condition statement that I didn't want to dig into that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reset `IY` to `0` after it reaches `5`. Change to:

```
#!/bin/bash 
NX="4"
NY="6"
echo "NX = $NX, NY = $NY"
IX="0"
IY="0"
while (( IX < NX ))
do
  while (( IY < NY ))
  do
    echo "IX = $IX, IY = $IY";
    IY=$(( IY+1 ))
  done;
  IY="0"
  IX=$(( IX+1 ))
done
```